# Interlocked.Increment is automatically called internally on method calls causing cpu overhead when multi-threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I searched for a question regarding this issue in google and stackoverflow and didn't find, so I hope to find an answer here.

**Foreword:**
I'm currently developing a performance critical application where I use multi-threading to share the work between all my processor cores for maximum throughput.

Interestingly I get more throughput natively by parallelizing my tasks in batches and processing them simultaneously. It doesn't matter, if I use the common ThreadPool or use my own thread pool, I'm experiencing the same issue.

Things I tested were Parallel(PLINQ) and Tasks, since they cause a memory allocation overhead on the heap, which I want to reduce as much as possible to reduce pressure on the GC.

---

**Issue:**
A function call within a thread running concurrently, is implicitly calling the System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment method, causing massive overhead especially in recursive functions running on the thread.

I profiled the application to investigate into this issue but it seems, that every function call, which has to implicitly secure the stack frame it's running on, calls this method - probably to ensure the local variables have been secured thread-safe.

The interlocking seems to be managed by the main thread, which causes a massive bottle neck.

[Profiling 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyjiK.png)

The marked line is where the function is internally called. Ignore the very red lines at the bottom, those relate to the recursive nature of the function call. The numbers are actually so big, because of this issue.

[Profiling 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6UCR.png)

I can reduce the implicit calling of this method by in-lining the code on smaller functions. However this doesn't help me with recursive calls. As you can see in the following image, each call branches into this function, causing overhead on the main thread.

[Profiling 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCPqJ.png)

The thread will be initialized by the following snippet. "action" is the function I want to execute on the thread an "l_state" will be additional data given by the caller.

```
ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem((l_state) =>
{
    action(l_state);

    //Other code omitted for brevity
}, state);
```

And this is the function which will be called and the profiling is referring to.

```
public void ProcessCollisions(Collider collider)
{
    var result = _tree.Query(in collider.Bounds);

    //Other code omitted for brevity
}
```

**Note:**
I'm queuing more work items in the common ThreadPool than I have processor cores. This is purposely done, due to gaps when scheduling a thread to keep it running and use the cpu cores more efficiently.

For each collider, I'm queuing one work item in the common ThreadPool. Since the ThreadPool threads are long-lived, they will process each item eventually. There could be ten-thousands of items queued in the ThreadPool.

---

**Things considered**

- Use self-managed threads instead of the common ThreadPool

  Had no effect on the described issue.
- In-lining function calls

  A workaround but not a solution

  Not applicable to recursive function calls
- Using PLINQ

  Causes internal heap memory allocations. Thus not applicable
- Using Tasks

  Causes internal heap memory allocations. Thus not applicable

---

**Question**
What am I possibly overlooking, regarding the execution of the threads? Could it be the common reference and usage of the the internal array of "_tree" within the "Query_Internal" function, or is there some implicit runtime handling regarding the syncing of the threads?

Comment: Local variables live on the stack, and each thread has its own stack. So you typically don't have to worry about those, unless you're sharing references (`ref`, that is) to them. Do you know who is calling `Interlocked.Increment`? Your profiler can probably tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm aware that each thread has its own stack and thus variables are tracked either as a reference or copied into the scope of the thread's stack. Unfortunately, the questions is mainly regarding exactly this question of what is calling the `Interlocked.Increment` function. As you can see from the [Profiling 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCPqJ.png), the function will be called, but not within the method itself, but outside, probably the runtime.